# Several (advanced) L'Hospital problems

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Problems : 
$$
\begin{align}
&\text{A}.\ \lim_{x\rightarrow1}(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\\
&\text{B}.\ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\cot x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&\text{C}.\ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{\tan^{-1}x-x}\\
&\text{D}.\ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\\
&\text{E}.\ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(a^x+b^x\right)^\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
$$

---

Here are my solutions concerning A~E.

A. $$\ln y=\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\ln(x-2)=\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{\ln(2-x)}}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{\ln(2-x)}}=_H\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\sec^2(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{x-2}=\infty$$so, $$A\rightarrow \infty$$
Is this conclusion right?

C.
$$=_H\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1}=_H\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^3}}(-2x)}{-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}}=\frac{1}{-2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: ..and your solutions are...??

Comment: sorry I'm working on it. I'm not used to writing math syntaxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1}(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}&=\lim_{x\to1}\exp\left[\ln(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\exp\left[\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\ln(2-x)\right]\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\exp\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\ln(2-x)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\ln(2-x)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac{\pi }{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\ln(2-x)-\frac{1}{2-x}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}{-\frac{\pi }{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\frac{0-\frac{1}{2-1}\cdot1}{-\frac{\pi }{2}\cdot1}\right]\\
&=\color{blue}{\exp\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)}.
\end{align}
$$
Note that it is valid to move the limit inside the exponential function since the exponential function is continuous.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: really nice layouts, easy to understand. thanks!

Comment: @GuidoDiPietro You are welcome. I leave the rest for you. For D, you can use similar method like my approach. For C, let
$$
\begin{align}
y=\sin^{-1}x\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sin y=x\quad\stackrel{\text{derivative}}\Rightarrow\quad y'\cos y=1.
\end{align}
$$
Since $\sin y=x$, then $\cos y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Thus, $y'=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to do that with hopital?

Because all those limits are trivial if you use taylor approximations;

$\sin x \sim x - \frac{x^3}{6}$, $\cot(x) \sim \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{3}$ $\arcsin x \sim x + \frac{x^3}{6}$, $(1 + x)^\alpha \sim 1 + \alpha x + \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)}{2} x^2$ etc..

Just substitute and you're good.

Comment: kinda good approach! but it is required to do with hopital in the problems except for D,E.

Comment: @GuidoDiPietro I see. Remember this method for the next time though, because generally it is way easier to apply than hopital :-)

Comment: thanks for your generous advice. I'll keep in mind that. :)

Comment: you're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\cot x-\frac1x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x\sin x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-x\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+x\cos x}=$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\frac{\sin x}x+\cos x}=-\frac0{1+1}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For example A,D and E

1. put $y=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$
2. Apply ln as $\ln y=\ln\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a} \ln f(x)$
3. use L'Hopital rule
4. $\ln y=l\implies y=e^l$
   For A
   $$y=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}
   \\ \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\ln (2-x)^{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}
   \\ \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}\ln (2-x)
   \\ \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{}\frac{\ln (2-x)}{\cot\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}=\frac{0}{0}$$  Now apply L'Hopital rule
   For E
   $$y=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(a^x+b^x\right)^\frac{1}{x}
   \\ \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\ln\left(a^x+b^x\right)^\frac{1}{x}
   \\ \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left(a^x+b^x\right)}{x}=\infty\implies y=\infty$$

Comment: Could you give me more specific equations for "E"?

Comment: @GuidoDiPietro I hope it helps out

Comment: Thanks for your generosity and effort. I'm moved.

Comment: It does(!) helps!